# TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()

Tags: odoo

I open a form view with many2many field and appear this error:

```
  File "/home/ingeos/coas/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ingeos/coas/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in 
   execute_cr
   return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ingeos/coas/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3623, in read
   result = self._read_flat(cr, user, select, fields, context, load)
  File "/home/ingeos/coas/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3744, in 
     _read_flat
   res2 = self._columns[f].get(cr, self, ids, f, user, context=context, 
  values=res)
  File 
  "/home/ingeos/coas/server/openerp/addons/one2many_sorted/__init__.py", line 113, in get
     o = getattr(o, m)
   File "/home/ingeos/coas/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 497, in 
__getattr__
  return self[name]
File "/home/ingeos/coas/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 468, in __getitem__
  elif field_column._type in ('one2many', 'many2many') and 
  len(result_line[field_name]):
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

Can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you ask something in odoo just add openerp tag alone we can understand your problem better.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because the Many2many field is empty .in odoo empty field is False. It's like you are doing.

```
        len(False)
```

Remember always check the field before you use it.

```
if rec.your_field_name:
            #then use it
```